# is python usable in MS Access without linking to the database

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, database-connection, pyodbc

New here with a problem I am trying to work out.

I was wondering if I had to connect python to my Access database for it to run a python file.

Basically, I want to click a button in Access and have it fire a python code to open a file dialog.

I would also like for the following to work:

Situation 1: can copy a path into an Access form
Situation 2: can open a merge which is is already linked to access

So, can I do something like that without connecting my python code to access?

Comment: Why would you need to call Python code for an action that can be done with VBA code? What is a 'merge'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the python code does not need to pull information from the Access tables then you don't need the script to connect to the Access database via pyodbc (or anything else). Given a test script ...

```py
# C:\__tmp\get_path.py
print(r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.pdf")
```

... the following VBA code ...

```vb
Sub getPathFromPython()
    Const pyInterpreter = "C:\Users\Gord\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"
    Const pyScript = "C:\__tmp\get_path.py"
    
    Dim objShell As New WshShell, objExec As Object
    Set objExec = objShell.Exec(pythonPath & " " & pyScript)
    Dim stdout As String
    stdout = objExec.stdout.ReadAll

    Debug.Print "Python code returned:" & vbCrLf & stdout
End Sub
```

... prints this in the Immediate Window of the VBA editor:

```
Python code returned:
C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.pdf
```